# Extracting measurements from a finger via ROI and image processing MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, usability, fingerprint, roi

I am trying to do a number of things via MATLAB but I am getting a bit lost with what techniques to use. My ultimate goal is to extract various measurements from a users fingerprint presentation, e.g. how far the finger over/undershoots, the co-ordinates of where the finger enters, the angle of the finger.

In my current setup, I have a web camera recording footage of a top down view of the presentation which I then take the video file and break down into individual frames. https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhvo1vs2615wr29/004.bmp?dl=0

What I am trying to work on at the moment is using ROI based image processing to create a binary mask around the edges of the scanner. I'm using the imbw function to get a binarised image and getting this as a result. https://www.dropbox.com/s/1re7a3hl90pggyl/mASK.bmp?dl=0

What I could use is some guidance on where to go from here. I want to be able to take measurements from the defined ROI to work out various metrics e.g. how far a certain point is from the ROI so I must have some sort of border for the scanner edges. From my experience in image processing so far, this has been hard to clearly define. I would like to get a clearer image where the finger is outlined and defined and the background (i.e. the scanner light/blocks) are removed.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you give an example of the code that you have used so far?

Comment: I = imread('004.bmp');
IG = rgb2gray(I);

% Create the gaussian filter with hsize = [5 5] and sigma = 3.5
G = fspecial('gaussian',[7 7], 3.5);
Note1f = imfilter(IG,G,'same');
BW = edge(Note1f,'sobel')

h_im = imshow(BW);
e = impoly(gca,[[157.153084982538 10.2962747380675;157.153084982538 225.430151338766;163.683934807916 236.186845168801;176.361466821886 245.022700814901;335.406868451688 245.022700814901;344.626891734575 238.491850989523;351.157741559953 228.887660069849;354.615250291036 11.8329452852153]]);
M = createMask(e,h_im);